# Android Room : Return Rows by custom date i.e -7day etc

Tags: android, android-room

I have overhauled my room database from String Dates to Date which is stored as a Long using type converters. I am unable to filter my results for specific times like -7 days or 3 months etc. Here is my configuration:

QUERY

```
 SELECT *
 FROM moodBeforetable
 WHERE moodBeforetable.workoutDate >= datetime('now', '-1 year')
 ORDER BY moodBeforetable.workoutDate DESC
 LiveData<List<WorkoutLogsAllPojo>> getAllMoodLogs();
```

The query works fine when the WHERE clause is commented out, however if I include that line above no data is returned.

This moodBeforetable.workoutDate variable is a DATE but its stored in the database as Long :1590705660000

Type Converter

```
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp){
    return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date){
    return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
```

Any assistance on the root cause of why the WHERE clause is not returning any data or the specified amount of rows would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `datetime('now', '-1 year')` returns timestamp as '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', for example 2019-05-28 23:29:42 ([docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). To get the number of milliseconds since epoch, use `1000 * strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-1 year'))` instead.

Comment: I updated my WHERE clause to: WHERE moodBeforetable.workoutDate >= 1000 * strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-30 day'))
Now it brings back all the rows, but its still not limiting them to the specified time limits like -1day or -7day it just brings back everything

Comment: Please post some workoutDate that is returned by mistake by this query

Comment: I'm not really sure how to show you this but you will have to take my word for it. if I change the constraint to -1day it will show rows from last month, changing -1day to -30 day has no impact on the results being brought back

Comment: If you use `WHERE moodBeforetable.workoutDate >= 1588118400 * 1000`, do you get the correct result? 1588118400 is the unix timestamp of 29th April 2020 (it can be obtained for example from [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php))